# Enabling Google Cloud Scheduler only during specific times (GCP)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

I have set up a Cloud Scheduler which invokes a cloud function every 15 minutes. How would I be able to disable the Cloud Scheduler from 8 am to 10 am for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*/15 0-7,10-23 * * *` this schedule should do what you want.

The event will fire on 0th, 15th, 30th and 45th minute of hours 0-7 and 10-23, each DOM, each month, each DOW.

per 
[1] [Configuring cron job schedules](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules) 
[2] [crontab(5) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) 
[3] [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_0-7,10-23_*_*_*)